# How to sort a CSV file by a column and then sort by a second column, then saving the CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I'm looking to read a CSV export file with PHP. I have access to the File Path Variable called `$file_path`.

How would I sort the CSV export file by a specific column and then sort it again by a second column? and then save the CSV file to the same file name and file path.

**UPDATE:**

I got it to read the CSV, then sort it and also save it to the CSV. However, it's also sorting the headers. I am trying to use array_shift and array_unshift but when I use `array_shift` with a multi-layer array, I am getting an error. (unshift works fine though).

```
function wp_all_export_after_export($export_id, $exportObj)
{
    // Check whether "Secure Mode" is enabled in All Export -> Settings
    $is_secure_export = PMXE_Plugin::getInstance()->getOption('secure');
    
    if (!$is_secure_export) {
        $filepath = get_attached_file($exportObj->attch_id);                    
    } else {
        $filepath = wp_all_export_get_absolute_path($exportObj->options['filepath']);
    }

    $handle = fopen($filepath, 'r') or die('cannot read file');
    $binNumber = array();
    $category = array();
    $rows = array();
    $header = array();
    
    
    //build array of binNumbers, Categories, and array of rows
    while (false != ( $row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',') )) {
        $binNumber[] = $row[3];
        $category[] = $row[1];
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    
    $header = $rows[0];
    array_shift($rows);

    //sort array of rows by BinNumber & then Category using our arrays
    array_multisort($binNumber,SORT_ASC, $category, SORT_ASC, $rows);

    array_unshift($rows,$header);
    
    $file = fopen($filepath,"w");
    foreach ($rows as $line) {
       fputcsv($file, $line);
    }
    fclose($file);
}

add_action('pmxe_after_export', 'wp_all_export_after_export', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi Gaby, 

what is the code you currently have? Where are you stuck?

Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: since you've provided no code of yours I can only give few hints: read file into an array with `fgetcsv()`, sort it with `array_multisort()` then save it using `fputcsv()`

Comment: Thank you @DINK74 , thank you for your hints. I have used them and I am almost there! I got it to read the csv, then sort it and also save it to the csv. However, it's also sorting the headers. I am trying to use array_shift and array_unshift but when I use array_shift with multi-layer array, I am getting an error. (unshift works fine though)

Comment: Sample data! Where is the sample data? You're asking for help with data manipulation without actually showing us what the data is.

Comment: Just do `$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ',');` once before your loop, then you already have the header columns in your variable, and don't need to shift anything. Plus, $binNumber and $category won't contain the values from the header line then either, which I am guessing would be better to begin with, since you are using those in your sorting process.